Azure Functions: Force HTTPS redirection
have an azure function and I created couple rest api request via httpClient to external http api.
External resource doesn't have https address so I can use only http. All httpClient request goes to https address.
How can I disable this https redirection in Azure Function application?
I tried to find that but couldn't

Please provide your function code.

sorry, I won't be able to share the code, need to know about the configurations from azure portal.

Follow below steps to turn off the Https redirection:

Navigate to Function App=>Settings=>Configuration=>General Settings
Set Https only to off as below:


